# Polymer serve is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer, polymer-cli

Followed the steps mentioned in the following link:-

[plymer project site](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/first-element/intro#noinstall)

Running `polymer serve` doesn't work, although all the earlier steps mentioned in the site worked fine.

When i run `polymer serve`, It shows something like this:-

```
C:\Users\ama16\Desktop\polymer-first-elements>polymer serve
Node Commands

Syntax:
    node {operator} [options] [arguments]

Parameters:
        /? or /help   - Display this help message.
        list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster
        listcores     - List cores on the cluster
        view          - View properties of a node
        online        - Set nodes or node to online state
        offline       - Set one or more nodes to the offline state

For more information about HPC command-line tools,
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.
```

and http://localhost:8080/components/icon-toggle/demo/  :- site  can't be reached

Answer (score 0):

I think you failed to install polymer-cli.

If you success to install polymer-cli with
`npm install -g polymer-cli`,
then the output of
`npm -g list --depth=0`
should be like below.

`$ npm -g list --depth=0
C:\Users\tom\AppData\Roaming\npm
~~(package list)~~
+-- polymer-cli@1.9.10
~~(package list)~~`